# Java - Issue with registry adding space

Tags: java, path, space

I want to add a new entry in my windows registry. I'm using the following code:

```
String start_cmd = JAVABIN + " -jar " + outputJar.getAbsolutePath();

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"REG", "ADD", REGENTRY, "/v", "Vodemki_app", "/d", "\"" + start_cmd + "\"", "/f"});
pb.start();
```

So `REGENTRY` is my reg path (ex: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\...`.
`start_cmd` is a command that starts my jar file. It works well if my absolute path does NOT contain any space. But if I use a path like `C:\\Vodemki\\Desktop\\My Folder\\jarfile.jar`, everything goes wrong.

So my question is: Is there a way to use a path with space using my code? I know it's possible to use `\"my path\"`but is there a way to do that into escaped quote (ex: `\"java -jar \"my path with spaces\" \"`)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was quiet simple, replace the space char with `\s`.
Regards.